# How to properly update mem package within package-lock.json file

Tags: git, npm

I'm running npm version 6.1.0  There is is a package called mem within my package-lock.json file, which is not a part of my package.json file.  It is at version 1.1.0.  Unfortunately GitHub does not like it. Github quotes:

> In nodejs-mem before version 4.0.0 there is a memory leak due to old results not being removed from the cache despite reaching maxAge. Exploitation of this can lead to exhaustion of memory and subsequent denial of service.

From the terminal what is the proper way to update this specific mem package so that my package-lock.json reflects it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be careful, some of your dependencies are using this package. If you update `mem` manually some of your dependencies *could* break. As you pointed out that GitHub found a vulnerability you could try to run `npm audit fix` (NPMs automatically vulnerability fixes).

[GitHub also features automatic security patches](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-automated-security-fixes)

You can also find out which package is using `mem` by running `npm ls mem`.
Then update the top-level package by `npm update <package>`

If all of that doesn't help, I wouldn't recommend updating it manually. It could break more than it fixes.

Comment: Thank you for being transparent on the issue. This gives me good ground to work from.

Comment: It appears the npm-check was the culprit. Thank you for that code in using npm ls mem.

Comment: "npm audit fix" did the trick here for me thereby removing the security alert on Github.